# shortcuts in pdf file

Tags: beamer

i am doing a presentation on beamer and I would like to put some shortcuts. For example, I have 5 sections and I would pressing the key 3 i would like to be directed to section 3.
Would that be possible?

Thank in advance

Comment: I am not sure if this is on-topic here. The relevant part of your question doesn't seem to be TeX related.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, by the way! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @cfr it is possible in a pdf reader that supports pdf javascript

Comment: I was thinking I could do it by using some "label" in the tex file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If so, that further confirms my reluctance to enable javascript in document viewers.

Comment: @cfr as far as I could understand looking at the adobe docs even on windows with acrobat it's disabled for security reasons unless the reader explicitly opts in. And I could only tell that you can detect keystrokes, I got lost trying to work out what you could do with that information:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But some word processors have it enabled by default, even if Adobe's software does not... [I think you are right that it is disabled by default in `acroread` and acrobat etc.]

Comment: @cfr what's a word processor?:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 'Word processor: A software application designed to encrypt text by destroying the reader's desire to digest it. This form of encryption avoids the problem inherent in more traditional forms which depend on destroying only the reader's ability to digest the original, thereby ensuring that they constitute a challenge irresistible to all but the most incurious of creatures.'

Answer (score 2):

Short answer no.

Longer answer, it depends.

PDF in theory has a JavaScript extension that in theory allows scripting (and in particular detecting an onKeyPress event and then you can do any programmable action eg moving to a specific page. see fro example some notes at

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380293/Javascript-in-PDF

However currently only Acrobat has reliable support for that and even on acrobat mostly it is disabled for security reasons by default so you require the viewer to explicitly allow scripting from menu or registry settings.

TUG hosts a calculator demo made in context (which I couldn't get to work on current readers I have today although I used it at the time it was published)

http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/calculat.pdf

Or the acrotex project makes extensive use of this feature

http://www.acrotex.net/index.php?lang=en

So in theory you could probably add such a feature to a beamer presentation but it wouldn't be that easy and would probably only work in windows acrobat.